# add border to each row in a textarea object

Tags: html, textarea

Is it possible to style a border-bottom for **each row** in a textarea?

so that if rows="5" I will have 5 vertical stripes (one under each row)

Something like a border-collapse in a table object?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't style textarea rows, you can add a repeating background-image to gain the same effect.